# kendo grid new row be selected after add

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to be selected new row after that I add . 
for edition a selected row I used uid property , so after edition saved , the selected row is selected still. but for add it's not work because uid changes for new row .

```
private _comebackFromEdit(uid: number) {
    var contact = $("#contact-grid").data("kendoGrid").table.find('tr[data-uid="' + uid + '"]');
    $("#contact-grid").data("kendoGrid").select(contact);
}
```

Comment: What event do you fire this method from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var grid = $("#contact-grid").data("kendoGrid");
var row = grid.dataSource.add();
var contact = grid.table.find('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"]');

grid.select(contact);
```

Comment: Thanks for time . but wat about if I sort my grid?? maybe added item goes to second row .

Comment: thanks :) . it works . just notice for others if want to use :for example .    var row = grid.dataSource.add(**newContact**);